# Android studio on AMD - edit emulator in real time?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm following an android development course on Udemy. As I have an AMD processor, I have to run an emulator with ARM image. I'm running a nexus 5 emulator that way. It is super slow but it is working.

However, I can't drag or edit anything in real time on the emulator. The instructor video has him dragging the text box, changing the size and style of the text etc in real time. I can't do that on the emulator.

Is there a work around this or am I missing something?

I'd like to be able to do this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQAFz.jpg

At this moment emulator is no different from testing on a physical device, I do have an android phone.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Instant Run requires an Intel HAXM acceleated processor, I believe. You can try Genymotion for an overall faster emulator

Comment: Does that mean I can't do real time editing at all on AMD? Does Genymotion support that feature?

Comment: Not sure. I don't use Instant Run. I don't really see the need for it. I care more about the Java functionality, than looks, though and slap everything into a View. Genymotion definitely runs more quickly than the provided AVD images, though

Comment: Nvm, I solved it. My question wasn't even right in the first place. The problem was in the layout editor, not in the emulator. The rendering problem I had in layout editor was fixed when I changed the API to 23. 

Thank you for your help though. Much appreciated!

Comment: Ah... that's just a preview window. Not the emulator ;)